# How do I extract /mnt/datalake/ out of dbfs:/mnt/datalake/?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting output of `dbfs:/mnt/datalake/`

I want to extract only `/mnt/datalake/`

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why don't you just ``.split(':', 1)``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
import re

st='dbfs:/mnt/datalake/'
print(re.search('(/\w+)+/',st).group())
```

Output:

```
/mnt/datalake/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply split it at `:` and extract the second part :

```
s = 'dbfs:/mnt/datalake/'
s = s.split(':')
print(s[1])
```

Edit : It is safer to use `s.split(':',1)` since there is a possibility that `:` may occur in the path required as output. The second argument defines how many times the string should be split

Comment: It may be prudent to use ``s.split(':', 1)`` to stay robust if ``:`` might occur in the path itself.